# Filter rows based on a series pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been facing a problem to filter out values in a column. I have a dataframe (data) which looks like the one below.

```
 Index                                                            Value
2019-11-22 00:00:00                                                0.0  
2019-11-22 00:05:00                                                1.0  
2019-11-22 00:10:00                                                2.0  
2019-11-22 00:15:00                                                3.0  
2019-11-22 00:20:00                                                4.0  
2019-11-22 00:25:00                                                5.0  
2019-11-22 00:30:00                                                6.0  
2019-11-22 00:35:00                                                7.0  
2019-11-22 00:40:00                                                8.0  
2019-11-22 00:45:00                                                0.0  
2019-11-22 00:50:00                                                0.0  
2019-11-22 00:55:00                                                1.0  
2019-11-22 01:00:00                                                2.0  
2019-11-22 01:05:00                                                3.0  
2019-11-22 01:10:00                                                4.0  
2019-11-22 01:15:00                                                5.0
```

I want to keep the series of values which go above 5 and want to assign all others as zero. For example, if the values are from 1-5, all the previous values before 5 should be set to zero and if there are eight rows with values from 1-8, the code should keep them as it is.The final output should be the following.

```
 Index                                                            Value
2019-11-22 00:00:00                                                0.0  
2019-11-22 00:05:00                                                1.0  
2019-11-22 00:10:00                                                2.0  
2019-11-22 00:15:00                                                3.0  
2019-11-22 00:20:00                                                4.0  
2019-11-22 00:25:00                                                5.0  
2019-11-22 00:30:00                                                6.0  
2019-11-22 00:35:00                                                7.0  
2019-11-22 00:40:00                                                8.0  
2019-11-22 00:45:00                                                0.0  
2019-11-22 00:50:00                                                0.0  
2019-11-22 00:55:00                                                0.0  
2019-11-22 01:00:00                                                0.0  
2019-11-22 01:05:00                                                0.0  
2019-11-22 01:10:00                                                0.0  
2019-11-22 01:15:00                                                0.0
```

When I try

```
    data[data<5]=0
```

It just returns the values higher than 5. Any help will be great on this.

Comment: `data[data['Value']>5]=0` ?

Comment: That would assign all values above 5 as zero. I want to keep the entire series from 1-8

Comment: what defines what a "series of values" is in your column?

Comment: Can you please rephrase? You want to keep the first ascending sequence and when you reach 5, then start converting to zero each less than 5 element. Correct?

Comment: Please check the desired output in the question.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Yes, I think I described the output. But the dicription is misleading.

Comment: warped answer would work, but the original dataframe values greater that 5 would be overwritten - save the new dataframe to preserve the original data with .copy()

Comment: But the final output that you are showing has values less than 5.

Comment: @ThanasisMattas, if there are eight rows with values from 1-8, the code should keep them as it is. But if there are five rows with values from 1-5, the code should set all of them to zero. I hope I'm clear now

Comment: Updated the question for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(index_col=0, sep='\s\s+')

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

grp = df['Value'].diff().lt(0).cumsum()

df_out = df.where(df.groupby(grp)['Value'].transform('max').gt(5), 0)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
                     Value
Index                     
2019-11-22 00:00:00    0.0
2019-11-22 00:05:00    1.0
2019-11-22 00:10:00    2.0
2019-11-22 00:15:00    3.0
2019-11-22 00:20:00    4.0
2019-11-22 00:25:00    5.0
2019-11-22 00:30:00    6.0
2019-11-22 00:35:00    7.0
2019-11-22 00:40:00    8.0
2019-11-22 00:45:00    0.0
2019-11-22 00:50:00    0.0
2019-11-22 00:55:00    0.0
2019-11-22 01:00:00    0.0
2019-11-22 01:05:00    0.0
2019-11-22 01:10:00    0.0
2019-11-22 01:15:00    0.0
​
```

Comment: Done! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
filter = data["Value"].where(data["Value"] > 5, 0)
indices_with_6 = filter[filter == 6].index
for idx in indices_with_6:
    filter[idx - 5: idx] = [1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]
print(filter)
```

```
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6
7     7
8     8
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```